# The images that i put in my html code don't work

Tags: html

So I've been trying to put images in my html code but they don't display and I don't see them. It's weird but images that are already saved in my computer from 3 weeks ago work when i put them in my code. But if i put an image that I recently downloaded, those images don't work. I'm not a total beginner and I know that I'm doing it right i think, cuz the old images are working, but not the new ones. That's my code:

```
    <div class= "logo">
        <img src="logo3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <!-- image slider starts-->
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slides">
            <!--radio buttons start-->
            <input type= "radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio1">
            <input type= "radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio2">
            <input type= "radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio3">
            <input type= "radio" name="radio-btn" id="radio4">
            <!--radio buttons end-->
            <!--slide images start-->
            <div class="slide first">
                <img src="radio1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="radio2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
<div class="slide">
    <img src="radio3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src= "radio4.jpg" alt="">  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you provide either screenshot of the directory? This HTML file is in the same directory as all the images?

Comment: It worked, thank you!! my files weren't in the same directory. now its working! @ProfessorAbronsius

Answer (score 0):

Use full path `"/folder/folder/image.jpg".` You use relative path `"folder/image"`.

What's the full path to image folder? Is this plain Java or do you use a framework like Spring?

*(Sorry for post, I can't comment because you need 50 reps and since 2 years I only have 11 rep and can only create posts.)*

PS: Please show HTML source code and console output in browser.